# How should I understand the nn.Embeddings arguments num_embeddings and embedding_dim?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to get used to the Embedding class in the PyTorch `nn` module.

I've noticed that quite a few other people have had the same problem as myself, and therefore posted questions on the PyTorch discussion forum and on Stack Overflow, but I'm still having some confusion.

According to the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#embedding), the arguments that are passed are `num_embeddings` and `embedding_dim` which each refer to how large our dictionary (or vocabulary) is and how many dimensions we want our embeddings to be, respectively.

What I'm confused about is how exactly I should interpret those. For example, the small practice code that I ran:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=10, embedding_dim=3)

a = torch.LongTensor([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]]) # (2, 4)

b = torch.LongTensor([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6], [3, 3, 3], [2, 1, 2],
                      [6, 7, 8], [2, 5, 2], [3, 5, 8], [2, 3, 6], [8, 9, 6],
                      [2, 6, 3], [6, 5, 4], [2, 6, 5]]) # (13, 3)

c = torch.LongTensor([[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]) # (2, 11)
```

When I run `a`, `b`, and `c` through the `embedding` variable, I get embedded results of shapes `(2, 4, 3)`, `(13, 3, 3)`, `(2, 11, 3)`.

What's confusing me is that I thought of the number of samples we have exceeds the predefined number of embeddings, we should get an error? Since the `embedding` I've defined has `10` embeddings, shouldn't `b` give me an error since it is a tensor containing 13 words of dimension 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, here is how your input tensor are interpreted:

```
a = torch.LongTensor([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]]) # 2 sequences of 4 elements
```

Moreover, this is how your embedding layer is interpreted:

```
embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=10, embedding_dim=3) # 10 distinct elements and each those is going to be embedded in a 3 dimensional space
```

So, it doesn't matter if your input tensor has more than 10 elements, as long as they are in the range `[0, 9]`. For example, if we create a tensor of two elements such as:

```
d = torch.LongTensor([[1, 10]]) # 1 sequence of 2 elements
```

We would get the following error when we pass this tensor through the embedding layer:

> RuntimeError: index out of range: Tried to access index 10 out of table with 9 rows

To summarize `num_embeddings` is total number of unique elements in the vocabulary, and `embedding_dim` is the size of each embedded vector once passed through the embedding layer. Therefore, you can have a tensor of 10+ elements, as long as each element in the tensor is in the range `[0, 9]`, because you defined a vocabulary size of 10 elements.